# NullPointerException while reading from a file

Tags: java, exception, pointers, null

I encounter a java.lang.NullPointerException error when running my Java program, and after reading up on it I think I understand what the error means, but I'm still not sure how to fix it.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
public class readFile {


public static ArrayList<String> pullFirst(String fileName) throws IOException{
    String filen = "C:\\Users\\Steven\\Desktop\\Tests\\wunderground\\outputTweetsWeather.txt";
    ArrayList<String> arl = new ArrayList<String>(); // java 6 ArrayList 

    FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(filen); // this is how you access a file in java
    DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(fs);
    BufferedReader bin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(din));

    String line;    
    while(!(line = bin.readLine()).startsWith("String index out of range")){ // read each line in the file while they exist
        arl.add(line);                // add them to the array list
    }

    return arl;                                  // return the array list
}

public static void main(String[] args, int j) {

    // this is just demo code to prove it works so you can check the output.
    try{
    ArrayList<String> rVal = pullFirst("testFile.txt");
        for(String a : rVal){
            //System.out.println(a + "\n"); // insert write to file code here
           if(a.startsWith("+t")){
       //          System.out.println(a);
           }
        }
        int i = 36;


        PrintStream out5 = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("forpopUp1.txt", true));

        System.setOut(out5);
     System.out.println(rVal.get(2 + j*i)); // Display Value


    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.print("Problem in readFile" + e);
    }

}
}
```

Now I'm not sure if it's to do with the fact that my main line is

```
public static void main(String[] args, int j) {
```

But, as far as I'm aware I have to have it this way, as this class is executed after an if condition from another class is ran, using the line

```
readFile.main(args, counterForreadFile);
```

This is the result of the StackTrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at readFile.pullFirst(readFile.java:22)
at readFile.main(readFile.java:33)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please add the complete stack trace

Comment: I suspect the problem is when the file is over - `BufferedReader` returns `null` when it does, and the condition in the `while` loop, which is invoking a method on a `String`, will then cause NPE. I cannot be sure until you provide the stack trace however

Comment: How do I get the stack trace?

Comment: In your catch block - ad `e.printStackTrace();` (If you do not catch the exception at all - it will be automatically shown, but you do catch an Exception here, so just print it)

Comment: If the exception take place in the code that you compile you should be able to get the number asking the compiler to keep debugging information in the bytecode. Typically with the '-g' option.

Comment: If you get the those line number showing please tell us what line that correspond in your code. That would make a big diff.

Comment: I've tried changing it to System.out.print("Problem in readFile" + e.printStackTrace()); but I get the error: 'The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) String, void'  ? And as just 'System.out.print(e.printStackTrace());' I get the error 'The method print(boolean) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments void' ?

Comment: @Steve: You do not need to add it in the `System.out.print()` or something - just add the command as it is in the catch block - it already prints it for you

Comment: @Steve: I added this indication to my answer, with the exact code you should put in your `catch` block. Hope that is clear enough.

Comment: Thanks I've edited my original post now with the result

Comment: @Steve: seems that amit is right as that is the line as counting backwards from the invocation pullFirst inside main that we know is at line 33.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the error is when the file you read was exhausted:

While reading the file:

```
while(!(line = bin.readLine()).startsWith("String index out of range")){ 
  ...
}
```

When the file is exhausted the `BufferedReader` will return `null`.

When you do `(line=bin.readLine()).startsWith(..)` you actually try to invoke `startsWith()` on `null` in this cases - and thus the error.

To solve this, you should iterate as:

```
while ((line = bin.readLine()) != null) { 
  if (line.startsWith("String index out of range")) break; 
  //rest of the code
}
```

This provide you `null` safety when the reader is exhausted.

While it is definetly an issue - I cannot be sure it is the exact problem you are encountering until you provide a full stack trace.

---

P.S. As I already said in comments - getting the stack trace (which provides more information on the issue) you can add to your `catch` block, so it will be something like that:

```
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.print("Problem in readFile" + e);
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

An alternative is to declare `main()` as `throws Exception`, and remove the `catch` block (and `try` block as well).

Comment: Would having while ((line = bin.readLine()).startsWith("String index out of range") != null) { 

Be okay? Not sure if you purposefully deleted that part of the line or not?

Comment: @Steve: No, it will cause the NPE in the cases I described. You should first check for null, and only if it is not null invoke the new method. The condition I removed can be done inside the loop itself. See edit.

Comment: @Steve no, it won't instead try: "while ((line = bin.readLine()) != null && line.startsWith("String index out of range")) { ..." The right side of && won't be evaluated if the left side is not true so you should be safe.

Comment: @Steve of course I meant to negate the line.startsWith with a '!' a typo :-P

Comment: @amit seems that the break condition should just the opposite... i.e. the '!' must be dropped.

Comment: You've fixed it!!

I've literally been working on this one class for around 15 hours now over three days, desperately trying to fix error after error... I've tested it with one set of data, and everything's came out perfectly ... I'm going to take a day off, assuming everything's working now for all data sets, before I dare test it again with some different input ;)

Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0):

In the catch(Execption e) replace

```
System.out.print("Problem in readFile" + e);
```

by

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

this show you the line error.